# Type mismatch. The return type 'Void' of best-match method on type is not compatible with the 'Result' argument supplied to InvokeMethod

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Getting Error while Invoking Workflow Activity in WCF Services

Type mismatch. The return type 'Void' of best-match method 'Mailsend' on type 'BusinessClass' is not compatible with the 'Result' argument supplied to InvokeMethod 'JobNotification', which expects return values of type 'String'.

Comment: you need to implement a method that returns type string

Answer (score 0):

It solved while defining Activity inArugment type of all the associated parameters.